# BigDecimal for Calculation with and Display of Stock Shares and Prices?

Tags: java, numbers, financial

I'm receiving flat files with the stock price and number of held shares for an account. One file contains the price and shares to 6 decimal places. The other file contains the price and shares to 12 decimal places.

The system needs to persist and later display these values (preferably to the number of decimal places received in the flat file). The price and shares will need to be used in calculations for performance (based on price changes) and holding percentages (based on shares). The performance and holding percentages only need to be displayed to two decimal places.

Will double meet my needs here or is BigDecimal more appropriate?

Comment: The reason that `decimal` types are used in money calculations is to avoid   "losing pennies"  due to rounding errors.  Bankers hate that; their calculations must reconcile down to the penny.  If you don't have this problem, `double` should be fine.

Comment: The calculations will result in percentages. The percentages need to be accurate to two decimal places. It seems that there are two primary reasons for not using `BigDecimal`, performance followed by ease of use. I'm not working with a large amount of data so performance is not concern. Accuracy (to the number of decimal places) is critical though.

Comment: For example, `double holdingPercentage = (sharesOfYahoo/totalAccountShares)*100.0;` If holdingPercentage could be 2.1149999999999998 when the actual value is 2.12, then I cannot use double. In that case, rounding the holdingPercentage using `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` would produce 2.11 which would be off by .01. @Robert Harvey - So, I suppose this is equivalent  "losing pennies" and therefore I would need to use BigDecimal. Do you agree? I would like to find example numbers for `sharesOfYahoo` and `totalShares` where this issue actually occurs. My example was just made up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `double` will not meet your needs.

If it wasn't for needing to do calculations `String` would best meet your needs.

That leaves `BigDecimal`.  It calculates slower than `double` but it will faithfully calculate every base 10 digit.

The problem with `double` is that the way it is displayed is an approximation of what it stores.  We display `double` in base 10 but store it in base 2.  This is fine when all it represents is measurements of continuous values like temperature.  Use it to represent discrete base 10 decimal values like money and you're inviting [Ron Livingston](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlRG9x0JRMc&feature=youtu.be&t=2m4s) and [Richard Pryor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLw9OBV7HYA) to steal your half pennies.

It seems like `double` should be discrete as well.  After all it's stored in ones and zeros as well.  In reality it is.  But base 2 discrete and base 10 discrete don't always match up as I can show with two rulers that divide up inchs differently.  Every value of both rulers can be perfectly represented in our computers if `BigDecimal` represents the top ruler and `double` represents bottom ruler.  However, you can't always perfectly convert from one to the other.

[image]

Both match at 1 inch.  They match at 1/2 inch.  They don't match at 1/10th inch.  To get to 1/10th you have to divide by 5.  `double` only knows how to divide by 2.

Making this worse is `double` will try to get close to 1/10th. And may even round the display to where it looks like .1 is in there.  But since it isn't really in there the amount it's off by is just waiting to mess up your calculations.

Trying to `double` your money is trouble.

Comment: So what is one dollar divided by 3 when using BigDecimal? BigDecimal doesn't get you out of trouble if you don't know what you are doing, and double works just fine if you know what you are doing as long as your numbers don't exceed trillions of dollars. And if your numbers exceed trillions of dollars, you don't ask on programmers.stackexchange.

Comment: @gnasher729 1/3rd isn't the same problem at all.  Like Pi, 1/3 can't be perfectly expressed in either system.  So there is no expectation of perfect representation.   0.1 however can be perfectly expressed, in base 10 but not base 2. It's the difference between which numbers can be perfectly expressed subverting expectations that causes the problem.  Typing 0.1 in Java won't get you a perfect base 10 number. Not exceeding trillions won't keep you out of trouble.